# Cloud Service Providers for High Performance Application Benchmarks

Tags: hosting, cloud-hosting

Are there any providers of cloud resources that are suitable for the benchmarking of high performance/high throughput applications?

In particular, machines with a minimum of 8 cores (preferably 16/32), that can sustain sequential local disk read speeds > 550Mb/s and the machines are connected via 10GE.

If there are no cloud providers can this resource be 'rented' on casual basis?

Thanks,
Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the cloud performance comparisons?  It is starting to be interesting to compare the performance between each cloud provider.  Have a look at [Cloud Harmon Speed Test Results](http://blog.cloudharmony.com/2010/02/cloud-speed-test-results.html)

Another one to look at is [Cloud Sleuth](https://www.cloudsleuth.net/web/guest/cloud-performance-analyzer)